# Classic ASP - Regular Expression Function

Tags: regex, asp-classic

I've just put together this regExp function that checks the contents of a string. The string should only contain numbers, letters, fullstops (.), hyphens (-), at signs (@) and apostrophes (').

```
If Trim(Request("searchStr")) <> "" Then
    Function validateSearchStr(searchStr) 
        Set regEx = New RegExp 
        regEx.IgnoreCase = True
        regEx.Pattern = "[\w'-@.]" 
        validateSearchStr = regEx.Test(searchStr)
    End Function

If NOT validateSearchStr(Trim(Request("searchStr"))) Then
    Response.Redirect("error/?e=badInput")
End If
End If
```

But this doesn't seem to be doing anything, at all. I can type all characters and symbols and the error page does not fire.

Is it obvious?

Comment: @Saurabh - Thanks for the edit, I forgot the code tags - oopsie :-p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, if you want to match a literal hyphen in the character class, you need to escape (ie backslash) it: `regEx.Pattern = "[\w'\-@.]"`.

Second, note `\w` allows underscores as well -- if you didn't want that use `A-Za-z0-9`.

Second off, it looks like `validateSearchStr` just tests if there is *any* character in your string that *matches* your regex.

So the searchstring 'abcasdf#ljasdf' is invalid, but since it matches `[A-Za-z0-9'\-@.]` (for example the first "a" matches), no error is thrown.

I think you should instead test if there are any *illegal* characters. i.e.:

```
regex.Pattern = "[^A-Za-z0-9'\-@.]"
```

Note the `^` in the character class which says "any character *but* these".

Now the `regEx.Test` will return TRUE *if* there is a bad character in the search string.
So rename `validateSearchStr` to `isSearchStrBad` and do:

```
If isSearchStrBad(...) Then
 ....
```

(Note, if you want to test whether the *entire* string is valid your regex would have to be `"^[A-Za-z0-9'\-@.]+$]"`, i.e. make sure every character of the string matches, not just one character).

Comment: I don't seem to be able to get this working. I made the changes as you suggested but I can still enter bad characters. If I do this: [If isSearchStrBad(str) = False Then] it fails just typing normal strings. If I change it back to True, it should fail on bad characters but it doesn't...

Comment: [Here](http://regexr.com?2vsvn) is the regex in action - the idea is that if any single character matches the "bad character" regex then `regEx.Test` should return True. So the regex is fine. As to why the code isn't working - I'm not sure I can help you :( ASP is not really my thing. Perhaps you could try the second regex (in action [here](http://regexr.com?2vsvq)) to validate the entire string as opposed to noticing a bad string? good luck!